Responsive CSS Text Frame Decoration
Im Trying to create a paragraph that is inside a two divs and where there is a decoration on each side. I can get this to work with absolute pixel Values but trying to make it responsive with relative (percentual) values is not working for me. It should look like this:

I am trying to have a green div as background with a padding, a white div where the paragraph element will be and and between that the same picture left and right, one rotated. Im using the .green-frame as relative container to position the decoration absolute. I wanna have the decoration fixed to the side of the white div.
From my understanding it should work with top: 50% and left/right: ~10% to position the images in the middle and ~10% under the white div. But in practices it works totally different then i expected. To position the image in the middle it takes 20%-25% and left/right is 0. When i change the screen size the images moves more under or over the white div. I am trying to get it stick to the side.
I tried with sticky and ::before and ::after with background-image of the div, i made a fiddle where i show my code. somehow i had to flip the right image in the element since putting it in .righ-deco puts the image at the top. How can i have the deco elements to keep in the middle an allways at a fraction under the .text-frame?


.green-frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #228B22;
  z-index: 0;
}

.text-frame {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left-deco {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
  z-index: 1;

}

.right-deco {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 20%;
  z-index: 1;


}

p {
  padding: 1rem;
}
<div class="green-frame">

  <div class="left-deco">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/4380/4380600.png" alt="decoration" class="left-deco">
  </div>

  <div class="text-frame">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

  </div>

  <div class="right-deco">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/4380/4380600.png" alt="decoration" class="right-deco" style="transform: scalex(-1);">
  </div>

</div>




top: 50% places the top corner of your image at the middle of its relative container. If you want the image to actually be centered in that dimension, you need to move it up by half the image height. The most convenient way to do that, is to apply transform: translateY(-50%)

In the other direction, things are complicated a bit by the fact, that we are dealing with a combination of padding in rem, and a width in percentage. You will likely have to involve calc() to resolve that.

this really helped my problem a lot! thank you! totally was not taking in account about the top corner...

You can use object-fit and eventually object-position and make each img  100% of height's container and around 120px of width.
take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit
Idea in the snippet below:


.green-frame {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #228b22;
  z-index: 0;
}

.text-frame {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 60px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left-deco {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 120px;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right-deco {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 120px;
  object-fit: contain;
  z-index: 1;
}

p {
  padding: 1rem;
}
<div class="green-frame">

  <div class="left-deco">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/4380/4380600.png" alt="decoration" class="left-deco">
  </div>

  <div class="text-frame">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

  </div>

  <div class="right-deco">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/4380/4380600.png" alt="decoration" class="right-deco" style="transform: scalex(-1);">
  </div>

</div>




the obect fit in addition to translate made it work, i posted the solution with percents only at the bottom

Thank you all very much! With a combination of the Information of the posts and a better understanding of the box model and its corners i found this solution,
somehow the text in the paragraph with z-index: 5 still stays under the image with z-index: 3 where it should in my mind be on top.


.hide-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.green-frame {
  position: relative;
    background-color: #ECF8E3;
    padding: 2rem;
    z-index: 0;
}

.green-text {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    border: 3px solid gold;
    z-index: 2;
  
}

p{
    font: 1rem "Segoe UI";
    z-index: 5;
}

.green-deco {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
.left-deco{
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    translate: -50% -50%;
}
.right-deco {
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    translate: 50% -50%;

}

.flip-deco {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.inward-deco {
    z-index: 3;
}

.center {text-align: center}
<div class="hide-overflow">
            <h1 class="center">Frame Outward Decoration</h1>
            <div class="green-frame">
              <div class="green-deco left-deco flip-deco"><img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/009/307/514/small/green-leaves-of-palm-tree-isolated-on-tranaparent-background-file-png.png"></div>
              <div class="green-text">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="green-deco right-deco"><img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/009/307/514/small/green-leaves-of-palm-tree-isolated-on-tranaparent-background-file-png.png"></div>
            </div>
          </article>

          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </p>

          <article>
            <h1 class="center">Frame Inward Decoration</h1>
            <div class="green-frame">
              <div class="green-deco left-deco inward-deco"><img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/009/307/514/small/green-leaves-of-palm-tree-isolated-on-tranaparent-background-file-png.png"></div>
              <div class="green-text">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="green-deco right-deco flip-deco inward-deco"><img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/009/307/514/small/green-leaves-of-palm-tree-isolated-on-tranaparent-background-file-png.png"></div>
            </div>
          </div>




Two background-images

The HTML is simplified down to a <p> nested within an <article> which is nested within the <main>.

The <p> is centered vertically and horizontally as a flex-item as is <article> being the flex-container for <p> and the flex-item of <main>.

There are two image-backgrounds in <main>. One is positioned left and center and the other is positioned right and center.

<article> floats above <main> with z-index: 1.

box-shadow was applied to <article> for depth (optional).

The font-size of :root (aka <html>) is 3vmax which is either 3/100th of the viewport width if the viewport width is larger than viewport height and vice versa. All rem units are relative to the :root font-size. So whenever the window is resized, all lengths in rem will scale automatically. In the comments there is an alternative font-size that uses the CSS function clamp().


View in Full page mode and resize the window.


/**
 * As an alternative replace `font` with:
 *   font-size: clamp(1rem, 8vw - 2rem, 3rem);
 *   line-height: 1.2;
 *   font-family: "Segoe UI";
 */
:root {
  font: 3vmax/1.2 "Segoe UI"
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #228B22;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 92%;
  height: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background:
  url(https://i.ibb.co/qrZ26xR/4380600.png)
  left center no-repeat,
  url(https://i.ibb.co/GMqjRZF/0060834.png)
  right center no-repeat #228B22;
  background-size: 7.5rem 7.5rem;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: calc(100% - 7.5rem);
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 0 0.75rem 1.75rem, 
  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42) 0 0.6rem 0.6rem;
}

p {
  padding: 1.25rem 1rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
}
<main>
  <article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </article>
</main>




this is working but i need the image which is much wider than the post itself to overflow, but your post puted me in the right direction!
